Vertical progressbar with vicious
I'm trying to create a vertical progressbar that shows memory usage. On 3.x AwesomeWM it works using
memwidget:set_vertical(true)

Now I'm trying to achieve the same with the following code:
memwidget = wibox.widget.progressbar()
membox = wibox.widget {
    {
        forced_height = 100,
        forced_width = 20,
        max_value = 1,
        widget = memwidget,
        border_width = 0.5,
        border_color = "#000000",
        background_color = "#494B4F",
        color = {
            type = "linear",
            from = { 0, 0 },
            to = { 0, 30 },
            stops = {
                { 0, "#AECF96" },
                { 1, "#FF5656" },
            },
        },
    },
    direction = 'east',
    layout = wibox.container.rotate,
}
-- Register mem widget
vicious.register(memwidget, vicious.widgets.mem, "$1", 11)


...


awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s)
...
    local right_layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()
    right_layout:add(memwidget)

But for some reason the widget effectively ignores the direction and rotation I set and shows me the progressbar of memory consumption from left to right direction, not vertical. What I'm doing wrong?!
Thanks!

There's 2 small problems here. First, you put memwidget in your right_layout instead of membox, which is why membox do nothing (it's not used). Second, replace widget = memwidget, with widget = wibox.widget.progressbar. Note the lack of (), widget takes the class name, not an object instance.

Thanks for your reply! Yeah, I messed up with names a bit. Anyway, when I changed widget = memwidget to widget = wibox.widget.progressbar the progressbar seems stopped getting the data from vicious.widgets.mem, it shows nothing :(

This page has an example how to integrate vicious with the dynamic syntax. Otherwise, your problem is probably that you are not passing the right progressbar object to vicious anymore since the changes I proposed in the last comment make a new progressbar rather than use your old variable
